# Can I customize the "display as" toggle on a list view to always display all options?

Tags: list-view, custom, button-overrides, list-button

In a list view, when you click on the "display as" button, it gives you the three options for displaying the list view. I wonder if there's a way to customize this so that the display as button is always toggled on and you can easily click back and forth between the three display options? Can it be placed elsewhere on the page?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, There is no such customization available to customize the display as option in List view. You might have to override the list view page itself with custom components to make such customization.